# Access Request email to Multiple accounts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, email, access

[image]

In SP2010 it's done as the image above is shown, just separate the email-addresses with a semicolon.
But in SP2013 I'm not getting this to work, is there a way around this?
I need two users to receive the access request emails.

Comment: It work in similar way in SP2013 too. Add one user and press Ctrl+K then hit space and add another user. Then again press Ctrl+K

Comment: Not working for me. CTRL+K(Check name) does not apply in that field.

Answer (score 6):

In SharePoint 2013 the delimiter changed to **comma**.

If this doesn't work something else is wrong - check ULS log in this case for errors (typo, SMTP error, ...).

Comment: Does not work in SP2013. Thats whats wrong.

Comment: Saw it working on a SP 2013 farm and in O365. Failed for me on one farm, but this was due to some SMTP error making single notifications fail as well.

Comment: I agree with Heinrich Ulbricht, I've just checked on my SharePoint 2013 on-premises environment - comma-separated emails worked fine for me, access request was sent to both email addresses. P.S. I've posted new answer, because I couldn't add a comment or vote for the Heinrich's answer.

Comment: In SP2013 it works with comma. Ex: user1@company.com,user2@company.com I put it without any space between.

Comment: This is great I just tested it on an on prem 2013 site and it works with commas. (adding a space after the comma didn't break it) The site approvers should have full control or at least a custom permission level that includes the "manage permissions" check box under the "site permissions" category. Does anyone know if there is a limit to how many approvers emails you can have for a site?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, you can enter only one email. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cece08f5-20eb-49a2-9106-8443d71a2e39/email-access-requests-to-multiple-emails?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly the fix you wanted, but I always recommend access requests go to a shared mailbox, rather than an individual account, as this way:
1. Multiple people can access the requests (as per your requirement)
2. If/when you leave the company/team, you can just give new the person access to that mailbox, and do not have to change all the access request settings in your sites and subsites.

Answer (score 0):

agree it should go to an alias/shared mailbox, but use a comma between names not a semi colon as there was a change in the source code from sharepoint between 2010-2013... works like a charm